# Gyroscopic forces due to counter rotating electric motors

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia, gyroscopes, precession

I am currently working on a tilt rotor aircraft, for that I need to size a motor the applies the torque to swivel the propellers from a down facing position into a rear facing position. We are using counter rotating propellers. H

I have troubles understanding how to calculate the torque required to rotate a spinning masses (electric motors) perpendicular to its rotational axis.
The motors are spinning with 5000 rpm around the X-Axis.

How would I go about calculating the torque required to rotate the entire assembly around the Y-Axis ?

The desired rotational speed around Axis Y is 1 rpm.

Mass of Electric Motors,            M_em = 11 kg .

Their Inertia L around the Y-axis,  L_yy = 0.0486 kg*m2

Motor distance from Axis,           r_em = .15 m

To keep things simple I assume that the mass and inertia pf the propellers is negligible compared to the mass and inertia of the electric motors.

Also, as far as I understand it, I am not talking about precession here. The precession of the two wheels would cancel each other out, also it "would be acting" around the Z-Axis.

I hope I was clear enough about explaining the problem and am happy to clarify if anything is unclear.

Thanks in advance for any help.

P.S. 
Is it possible I am overthinking this and the opposite angular momentum of the two spinning motors cancel each other out?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a free body diagram of sorts. At least take your diagram and add vectors and labels for things. Also, note the distance of each rotor center of mass to the central axis is $b$.

[image: fbd]

I have numbered the rotors **1** and **2** to distinguish them, and applied their rotational velocity vectors as follows

$$ \begin{aligned} \vec{\omega}_1 & = \pmatrix{-\omega \\ 0 \\0 } & \vec{\omega_2} & = \pmatrix{ \omega \\ 0 \\ 0} \end{aligned} $$

where $\omega$ is the magnitude of rotation in radians per second.

Each rotor can also apply a torque to the system in the same direction as its rotation

$$ \begin{aligned} \vec{\tau}_1 & = \pmatrix{-\tau_1 \\ 0 \\0 } & \vec{\tau_2} & = \pmatrix{ \tau_2 \\ 0 \\ 0} \end{aligned} $$

Additionally, the central axis is assumed to be already in motion with rotational velocity and the applied torque about the negative *y* axis

$$ \begin{aligned} \vec{\omega}_0 & = \pmatrix{0 \\ -\omega_0 \\ 0 } & \vec{\tau_0} & = \pmatrix{0 \\ -\tau_0 \\ 0} \end{aligned} $$

Now we need to include the reaction forces for each rotor mount as applied to each rotor

[image: fbd2]

The force vectors applied to each rotor are

$$ \begin{aligned} \vec{F}_1 & = \pmatrix{Fx_1 \\ Fy_1 \\ Fz_1 } & \vec{F}_2 & = \pmatrix{ Fx_2 \\ Fy_2 \\ Fz_2} \end{aligned} $$

Finally, the acceleration of each rotor's center of mass is linked to the motion of the central axis. Since there are no external forces applied we can assume without loss of generality that the coordinate system above (in black) has *zero* acceleration, but it can have rotational acceleration

$$ \begin{aligned} \vec{a}_0 & = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0 } & \vec{\alpha}_0 & = \pmatrix{ 0 \\ -\dot{\omega}_0 \\ 0} \end{aligned} $$

Now we can state the equations of motion. We need 6 equations for each rotor and 6 for the central body, **although we ignore its mass properties** and just assume the net forces and moments acting on the central shaft are zero.

And here are all the equations in all their glory:

<sub>$$ \begin{aligned}\begin{pmatrix}Fx_{1}\\
Fy_{1}\\
Fx_{1}
\end{pmatrix} & =m\left(\begin{pmatrix}0\\
-\dot{\omega}_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}b\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\
-\omega_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}0\\
-\omega_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}b\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}-m\,b\,\omega_{0}^{2}\\
0\\
m\,b\,\dot{\omega}_{0}
\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}-\tau_{1}\\
My_{1}\\
Mz_{1}
\end{pmatrix} & =\begin{bmatrix}I_{xx}\\
 & I_{yy}\\
 &  & I_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-\ddot{\theta}_{1}\\
-\dot{\omega}_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-\dot{\theta}_{1}\\
-\omega_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}I_{xx}\\
 & I_{yy}\\
 &  & I_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-\dot{\theta}_{1}\\
-\omega_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-I_{xx}\ddot{\theta}_{1}\\
-I_{yy}\dot{\omega}_{0}\\
\left(I_{yy}-I_{xx}\right)\omega_{0}\dot{\theta}_{1}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned} \tag{rotor 1}$$
$$\begin{aligned}\begin{pmatrix}Fx_{2}\\
Fy_{2}\\
Fz_{2}
\end{pmatrix} & =m\left(\begin{pmatrix}0\\
-\dot{\omega}_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}-b\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\
-\omega_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}0\\
-\omega_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}-b\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}m\,b\,\omega_{0}^{2}\\
0\\
-m\,b\,\dot{\omega}_{0}
\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}\tau_{2}\\
My_{2}\\
Mz_{2}
\end{pmatrix} & =\begin{bmatrix}I_{xx}\\
 & I_{yy}\\
 &  & I_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\ddot{\theta}_{2}\\
-\dot{\omega}_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}\dot{\theta}_{2}\\
-\omega_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}I_{xx}\\
 & I_{yy}\\
 &  & I_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\dot{\theta}_{2}\\
-\omega_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}I_{xx}\ddot{\theta}_{2}\\
-I_{yy}\dot{\omega}_{0}\\
\left(I_{xx}-I_{yy}\right)\omega_{0}\dot{\theta}_{2}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned} \tag{rotor 2}$$
$$\begin{aligned}-\begin{pmatrix}Fx_{1}\\
Fy_{1}\\
Fx_{1}
\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}Fx_{2}\\
Fy_{2}\\
Fz_{2}
\end{pmatrix} & =\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}0\\
-\tau_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}-\left(\begin{pmatrix}-\tau_{1}\\
My_{1}\\
Mz_{1}
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}b\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}Fx_{1}\\
Fy_{1}\\
Fx_{1}
\end{pmatrix}\right)-\left(\begin{pmatrix}\tau_{2}\\
My_{2}\\
Mz_{2}
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-b\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}Fx_{2}\\
Fy_{2}\\
Fz_{2}
\end{pmatrix}\right) & =\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned} \tag{center}$$</sub>

These equations are be solved given the known motion $\omega_0$ and $\dot{\omega}_0$ for all the forces and torques. there are more equations than unknowns because several of the equations will just end being like 0=0. You have to include the mass properties of the central body in order to solve this completely.

After doing all that, I end up with

$$ \tau_0 = 2 \left( I_{yy} + m b^2 \right) \dot{\omega}_0 $$

which means, **you can just use the parallel axis theorem to get the effective mass moment of inertia and just use that.**